# Virtual destructor for non pointer member variables

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, destructor

I have a question regarding virtual destructors. I know that if a variable pointer is polymorphic it is neccesary to create a virtual destructor, but if I don't need to do any destruction specific code is it necessary?

For example, the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct ExtraData
    {
        int myType;
    }
    struct BarData : public ExtraData
    {
        std::string myName;
        float myFoo;
    }
    struct BooData : public ExtraData
    {
        int myBoo;
        double myTime;
    }
    Foo() {}
    ~Foo() { delete myExtradata; }

    int myA;
    int myB;
    ExtraData* myExtraData;
};
```

myExtraData is created from outside the struct, it can be either via new BarData() or via new BooData(). Would BarData and BooData need a virtual destructor. Or since they don't have member pointer it's okay?

Comment: `but if I don't need to do any destruction specific code is it necessary` - but in the example you do need it :D

Comment: i was a bit confused (and I am still) about the `Foo`. Isnt that `Foo` irrelevant to the desructors of the nested classes?

Comment: if class represents a value object destructor shouldn't be a virtual. If class is used with polymorphism virtual destructor is obligatory.

Comment: Your `Foo()` constructor fails to initialize `myExtraData` which leads to UB on destruction if you ever happen to _not_ assign a pointer from outside!

Comment: @CiaPan this is a code example, myExtraData will always be set from outside the struct *myExtraData is created from outside the struct, it can be either via new BarData() or via new BooData()*

Comment: This should not even be a question.. All class that you expect can be inherited should have virtual destructors. Period. You do not know how someone (that includes you a couple of months later) will inherit your class and how they will use it.

Comment: @Rob: Wrong; classes that can be inherited but not instantiated (no public non-deleted constructors) do not need virtual destructors. E.g. policy classes can behave like this.

Comment: @MSalters Define "wrong" please.. Would it break something to have the destructor virtual in the case of a "policy" class?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, maintainability. The poor maintenance developer is going to waste quite a bit of time finding out that the policy class is indeed a proper policy class, despite the red herring.

Comment: @Rob If I have to get a vtable only for creating a virtual destructor I would preffer a different approach to my infrastructure. I was asking because I wasnt sure if it was needed for substructs that had POD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be UB to call:

```
Base* base = new Derived;
delete base; // UB here if ~Base is not virtual.
```

unless destructor of `Base` is `virtual`.

> 5.3.5/3 Delete
>
> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. In the second alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.73)

In your case, "static type of the operand" is `ExtraData` and "its dynamic type" is either `BarData` or `BooData`. So they are different, and the static type `ExtraData` must have a virtual destructor.

Comment: This is the right answer. The issue arises when you delete an object of a derived type through a pointer to the base type; if the base type does not have a virtual destructor the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `delete myExtradata;` the delete will have to know how to call the correct destructor for the object that is deleted. For that to work polymorphically, `ExtraData` needs to have a virtual destructor.

It's not only needed for pointers, but in this specific case I'm sure `std::string` in `BarData` has at least one pointer internally.

Comment: It's in fact common for `std::string` to have a union of a pointer and a `char[N]`, for some small N. That means only some `std::string` objects contain a pointer sub-object. Not that it matters, this is UB either way.